# When using the five-fold cross validation to train the network, some folds perform well and some perform poorly, how can I do

Tags: cross-validation, k-fold

I am trying to create a binary CNN classifier for a dataset (class 0 = 77 images, class 1 = 41 images), which I want to do 5-Fold cross validation. In each fold, using the validation sets to save best model, and sharing same model, Hyperparameters, and training strategy.  And here is my results.

- fold  - test sets accuracy
- fold0 - 0.68
- fold1 - 0.71
- fold2 - 0.91
- fold3 - 0.96
- fold4 - 0.64

My question is:
Fine tuning by changing the Hyperparameters. It was found that fold2 and fold3 performed better each time, but fold0 and fold4 performed poorly. What is willing to cause it and what should I do.

The possible problem is that each initialization is random.

Thank you all for your answers.

```py
import os
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from torch.utils.data.sampler import WeightedRandomSampler

import monai
from monai.data import NiftiDataset
from monai.transforms import Compose, AddChannel, ScaleIntensity, RandFlip, RandRotate, ToTensor
from monai.data import CSVSaver

from data_process import read_csv, get_sample_weights


def train(train_file, val_file, stage='exp0'):
    '''
    :param train_file:
    :param val_file:
    :param stage:
    :return:
    '''

    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0,1'

    img_src_path = '../samples/T1c_images/'  # 

    img_list_train, label_list_train = read_csv(train_file)
    img_list_val, label_list_val = read_csv(val_file)

   
    img_train = [os.path.join(img_src_path, i) for i in img_list_train]
    labels_train = [int(i) for i in label_list_train]

    img_val = [os.path.join(img_src_path, i) for i in img_list_val]
    labels_val = [int(i) for i in label_list_val]
    print('val images: ', len(img_val))

    # Define transforms
    # train_transforms = Compose([ScaleIntensity(), AddChannel(), Resize((182, 218, 182)),  RandRotate90(), ToTensor()])
    # val_transforms = Compose([ScaleIntensity(), AddChannel(),  Resize((182, 218, 182)), ToTensor()])
    train_transforms = Compose([ScaleIntensity(), RandRotate(range_x=45, range_y=45, range_z=45, prob=0.5),
                                RandFlip(prob=0.5, spatial_axis=1),  
                                AddChannel(), ToTensor()])  # if x=y=z   RandRotate90()
    val_transforms = Compose([ScaleIntensity(), AddChannel(), ToTensor()])

    train_ds = NiftiDataset(image_files=img_train, labels=labels_train, transform=train_transforms, image_only=False)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=2,
                              pin_memory=torch.cuda.is_available())

    # create a validation data_process loader
    val_ds = NiftiDataset(image_files=img_val, labels=labels_val, transform=val_transforms, image_only=False)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size=4, num_workers=2, pin_memory=torch.cuda.is_available())

    # Create DenseNet121, CrossEntropyLoss and Adam optimizer
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model = monai.networks.nets.densenet.densenet121(spatial_dims=3, in_channels=1, out_channels=2).to(device)
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
    loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=torch.Tensor([1, 1.2])).cuda()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), 1e-5)

    # start a typical PyTorch training
    epochs = 50
    val_interval = 1
    best_metric = -1
    best_metric_epoch = -1
    writer = SummaryWriter()
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print("-" * 10)
        print(f"epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}")
        model.train()
        epoch_loss = 0
        step = 0
        t_metric_count = 0
        t_num_correct = 0
        for batch_data in train_loader:
            step += 1
            # ptrint images name
            # print('image name', batch_data[2]['filename_or_obj'])
            inputs = batch_data[0].to(device)
            # print(inputs.shape)
            labels = batch_data[1].to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = loss_function(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            epoch_len = len(train_ds) // train_loader.batch_size
            # train acc
            t_value = torch.eq(outputs.argmax(dim=1), labels)
            t_metric_count += len(t_value)  # 
            t_num_correct += t_value.sum().item()  # 
           
            # print(f"{step}/{epoch_len}, train_loss: {loss.item():.4f}")
        epoch_loss /= step
        t_metric = t_num_correct / t_metric_count
        writer.add_scalar("train_loss", epoch_loss, epoch + 1)
        writer.add_scalar("train_acc", t_metric, epoch + 1)

        print(f"epoch {epoch + 1} average loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}")

        if (epoch + 1) % val_interval == 0:
            model.eval()
            with torch.no_grad():
                num_correct = 0.0
                metric_count = 0
                for val_data in val_loader:
                    val_images, val_labels = val_data[0].to(device), val_data[1].to(device)
                    val_outputs = model(val_images)
                    value = torch.eq(val_outputs.argmax(dim=1), val_labels)
                    metric_count += len(value)  # 
                    num_correct += value.sum().item()  # 
                metric = num_correct / metric_count
             
                if metric > best_metric:
                    best_metric = metric
                    best_metric_epoch = epoch + 1
                    save_path = 'checkpoint_07201/' + stage + '_' + str(epoch + 1) + "_best_metric_model.pth"
                    torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_path)
                    print("saved new best metric model")
                
                print(
                    "current epoch: {} current accuracy: {:.4f} best val accuracy: {:.4f} at epoch {}".format(
                        epoch + 1, metric, best_metric, best_metric_epoch
                    ))
                print('current train accuracy: {:.4f}, num_correct: {}, num_count:{}'.
                      format(t_metric, t_num_correct, t_metric_count ))
                    
                writer.add_scalar("val_accuracy", metric, epoch + 1)
    print(f"train completed, best_metric: {best_metric:.4f} at epoch: {best_metric_epoch}")
    writer.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # 5 folder
        for i in range(5):
            folder = 'exp'+str(i)
            train_path = './data/'+ folder +'/train.csv'
            val_path = './data/'+ folder + '/val.csv'
            train(train_path, val_path, stage=folder)
```

Comment: Can you share your code, so we can see what libraries and commands you are using?

Comment: the main code was already provided @RefaeIJan

Comment: What do you mean by "each initialization is random"? In addition, I can see that you are not creating the folds in the code, but you just load folds that pre-created before running the code. How the folders are creating? Manually? Is it constant or random?